# Stacking and balancing shapes in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I've been trying to make a similar stacking animation as shown in the following video at around 00:25. Shapes stacking on top of each other and then balancing. I've tried Newton, I've somewhat tried keyframing it myself, but I cannot get it to look as good. Does anyone have tips on how to do this?

```html
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/239566739?color=ffffff&start=59&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/239566739">Blockchain</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/buck">Buck</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new feature in ae called "Create Nulls From Paths" you find it under window. So select the shape you use, click on its path and select "create null from path" So what you can do now is link a new shape to the null from the first shape. Now its easy to make the same effect where they are connected.